# Term for a phrase with a word followed by its antonym

Tags: meaning

If I use the term "bitter-sweet", its a particular type of term, because sweet is the opposite of bitter, but I just can't recall what it's called. I've tried googling all sorts of variations of the title, but the only links that come up are thesauruses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term I believe you are thinking about is called 'Oxymoron'. Google definition: A figure of speech in which apparently contradictory terms appear in conjunction.
(Pretty ugly, Bitter-sweet, Act Naturally, Alone together)